# Custom exception in soap service Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, exception, soap

I want to send below class as custom exception from Spring Boot SOAP service, but I am not able to get custom class. I have tried lot but still not getting desired output.

```
public class Fault {
    @XmlElement(name = "InterfaceID")
    protected String interfaceID;
    @XmlElement(name = "TransactionID")
    protected String transactionID;
    @XmlElement(name = "ProjectName")
    protected String projectName;
    @XmlElement(name = "ProcessName")
    protected String processName;
    @XmlElement(name = "ComponentName")
    protected String componentName;
    @XmlElement(name = "ErrorCode")
    protected String errorCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "ErrorMessage")
    protected String errorMessage;
    @XmlElement(name = "ErrorDescription")
    protected String errorDescription;
    @XmlElement(name = "TimeStamp")
    protected String timeStamp;
    @XmlElement(name = "StackTrace")
    protected String stackTrace;
}
```

I have tried solution as below

// Declare Custom Soap Exception class

```
public class CustomSoapException extends RuntimeException  {
   private Fault fault;
   public CustomSoapException(Fault fault) {
        this.fault = fault;
    }
    public Fault getFault() {
        return fault;
    }
}
```

// Main class

```
@Endpoint
public class GetDataEndpoint{
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.my.com/schemas/Getdata.xsd";
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GetDataEndpoint.class.getName());

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetDataRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetDataResponse getData(@RequestPayload GetDataRequest request) {

        GetDataResponse response = new GetDataResponse();
        Fault fault = new Fault();
        FaultMessages faultmessages = new FaultMessages();

        try {
            int i = 1 / 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CustomSoapException(createDefaultFault(e));
        }

        return response;
    }
    private Fault createDefaultFault(Exception ex) {
        Fault fault = new Fault();
        fault.setErrorCode("500");
        fault.setErrorDescription(ex.getMessage());
        fault.setComponentName("MyService");
        fault.setInterfaceID("MyOperation");
        fault.setTransactionID("Testing");
        
        return fault;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomSoapException.class)
    public Fault handleCustomSoapException(CustomSoapException ex) {
        return ex.getFault();
    }
}
```

I am getting below output

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">com.ril.serviceimpl.CustomSoapException</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but i want output as a below said format can you please help me

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <InterfaceID>MyOperation</InterfaceID>
         <TransactionID>Testing</TransactionID>
         <ProjectName></ProjectName>
         <ProcessName></ProcessName>
         <ComponentName>MyService</ComponentName>
         <ErrorCode>500</ErrorCode>
         <ErrorMessage>Error in code</ErrorMessage>
         <ErrorDescription></ErrorDescription>
         <TimeStamp></TimeStamp>
         <StackTrace>Error at Line no 1</StackTrace>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```